# Can I trigger MFA while terminating EC2 instance from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

My IAM user is successfully authenticated to AWS console using MFA. I want to prevent the user from accidental delete of EC2 resources. I want the authenticated user to be prompted for MFA when he tries to delete an EC2 instance from the console. I tried using the inline policies with action set to allow stop/terminate instances and set a conditional permission for requiring MFA. But once the user is logged in the console the user is never prompted for MFA for stop/terminate instance actions. Below is my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not trigger additional authentication at the moment the user is making an API call.
The policy you created will ensure that **only** MFA'ed users can terminate an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could ensure that an mfa code is entered on (almost) every API call is:

1. Create a **new role** which is assumed by the user who wants to perform any of the mfa protected actions (terminate or stop instances).
2. Give the user who is permitted to perform the operations permission to assume the role.
3. Create and attach a policy to the role which gives access to the operations *ec2:TerminateInstances* and *ec2:StopInstances*.
4. Set the aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent condition on the newly created policy.
5. Set **another condition key**: *aws:MultiFactorAuthAge* [1] with a very low number of seconds (such as 10) on the newly created policy. This ensures that the user must assume the role every 10 seconds with a new token code.
6. Create a script which the user might call to trigger an mfa protected operation. The script prompts for the token code and passes it to the aws cli operation *aws sts assume-role* [2] with parameters *role-arn* set to the arn of your role created in step (1), *role-session-name* set to an arbitrary value, *serial-number* set to the serial number of your mfa device and *token-code* set to the value you prompted the user for.

#### References

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-enable-mfa-protection-on-your-aws-api-calls/ (Part 2 No. 2)
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html (section 'Using MFA with AssumeRole')